# Minecraft client fake or was this an error message releating to tumblr?

Tags: security, java, minecraft, tumblr

the other day I downloaded a fresh minecraft launcher jar and when I ran it I got a message in a blue box inside the launcher window that said "See, that's what the app is perfect for." and then in smaller text said "Sounds perfect Wahhhh, I don't wanna" I'm afraid this might have been a fake client but I did download it from https aws link from the official website. I think they use tumblr for a website thing inside the launcher and it might had been an error but I am confused and concerned.

Comment: Did it look like [this](http://unwrapping.tumblr.com/post/131445762927/sounds-perfect-wahhhh-i-dont-wanna)?

Comment: sort of but less fancy, it was a solid blue box with plain text printed over it.

Comment: I'd say it's potentially a harmless error; however I recommend waiting for someone else to confirm it.  I haven't seen that error much, so I'm not 100% sure.